# Stability Criteria of Type 3 Digital PLL

Tags: digital-logic, transfer-function, stability, pll, pole-zeroplot

I suppose we can derive the **stability criteria based on poles of open-loop transfer function** of F(z) in expression (4.11). However, the pole analysis does not help in deriving the stability criteria at expression (4.23)

Could anyone tell me if I had missed anything ?

[image: Type 3 DPLL block diagram]

[image: pole zero analysis]

[image: Stability criteria]

Answer (score 0):

The text indicates similarity between analog and digital PLL

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuidA2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the pole frequency of that 3rd pole is quite high, then the accumulated phase-shift contributes to ringing but is not enough to cause oscillation----- if the sampling rate is high enough.

Comment: This does not really answer the original question. I am asking about derivation of expression (4.23) using (4.11)